# Checking the execution of the method after clicking the button

Tags: jsf

I have button, whitch execute some method:

```
<h:commandButton value="click" action="#{taskController.startTaskUpload}"/>
```

This button is available to anyone who visits the page. How can I make a test like this: if one of the users pressed this button and the method is executed, if any other user presses this button, the method did not start again?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Your task should have a state persisted somewhere (like a database), then you could do something like

```
<h:commandButton value="click" action="#{taskController.startTaskUpload}" disabled="#{taskController.task.running}" />
```